# how to get the number of rows of mysql db with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i would like to get the number of rows of a mysql database table with one single statement or a function

```
include "opendatabase.php"; //opens database

while (NUMBEROFROWS > 0){
    //do something
}
```

the `NUMBEROFROWS` should be replaced with the statement that returns the number of rows

i already tried to create a function

```
function getRowNumber(){
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  `votes`";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connect);

    list($length) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    return $length;

}
```

but it does not work if i dont put the `include "opendatabase.php";` in it.

what am i doing wrong

Comment: Initialize the database connection in `opendatabase.php` and pass the connection link as a parameter to your function.

Comment: It's a scope issue. Your DB connection should be made global (which is not recommended) or passed through the function itself.

Comment: what error do you get when you dont use `include "opendatabase.php";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // rows found..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that `include "opendatabase.php";` runs in another scope like described here

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

there is a `global $connect` missing within the function

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
function num(){
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
  if(mysql_num_rows($data) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){
      // do something with your data..
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

would this work for you ?

```
  function getRowNumber()
{
   $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as counts FROM  `votes`";
   $result = mysql_query($query, $connect);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   $counts = $row['counts'];
return $counts;

}
```